# How to configure onedrive to sync Business shared folders

Tags: 20.04, mount, sync, cloud, office365

I'm quite new to Linux, and have been trying [this client](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/releases) to sync OneDrive files. It initially works for personal files, but not for shared folders. I believe I need to configure this functionality as per

https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/BusinessSharedFolders.md

However, I find this step hard to understand:

---

**Configuring OneDrive Business Shared Folders**

- Create a new file called 'business_shared_folders' in your config directory
- On each new line, list the OneDrive Business Shared Folder you wish to sync

```
[alex@centos7full onedrive]$ cat ~/.config/onedrive/business_shared_folders
# comment
Child Shared Folder
# Another comment
Top Level to Share
[alex@centos7full onedrive]$
```

---

I created a text file *'business_shared_folders'* inside *.config*, but I can't figure out what "Child Shared Folder" and "Top Level to Share" mean, neither what I should write in "[alex@centos7full onedrive]" (maybe exactly as it appears in the terminal before '$'?). Sorry if the question is too basic.

I tried other clients such as [Onedriver](https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver), but couldn't find instructions about how to configure it to cync shared folders from Business.

Comment: CentOS is not supported on AskUbuntu, but you may find an answer on [the CentOS Forums](https://forums.centos.org) 

Comment: RE: CentOS is not supported on AskUbuntu, but you may find an answer on ... That is the example taken directly from the documents.

Comment: The best is using onedriver (it has a GUI). It's perfect. https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a text file 'business_shared_folders' inside .config, but I can't figure out what "Child Shared Folder" and "Top Level to Share" mean

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

This is just an example configuration.

On each line, you type the name of the Shared Folder that has been shared with you. To get the right folder name(s) to add, as per the documentation, you use: onedrive --list-shared-folders

Additionally, rather than posting here, next time please ask your question here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/discussions

Comment: The best is using onedriver (it has a GUI). It's perfect. https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

Comment: The 'onedrive' client also has a GUI for folk that want a GUI - https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI